# Format and Restore Mac from Time Machine, without disturbing Bootcamp

Tags: mac, bootcamp, restore

I want to format my Mac's internal drive, but I have Bootcamp installed and I don't want to disturb it.

Is it possible to take a backup using Time Machine and then format the Mac, later restore the entire Mac from Time Machine without affecting Bootcamp?

**If yes, How do I do it?**

Comment: Why? Reformatting then restoring with Time Machine will just put the machine back exactly how it was.

Comment: This is like asking us to run a marathon for you. Those that have run one, know the training and time needed. There’s no easy way to prepare you remotely for “how to do this” and what if we are wrong, you still need a backup in case a step fails you.

Comment: I am facing some lag issues ,which can be resolve by this.

Comment: Perhaps formatting the internal drive will not require backing up Windows (Boot Camp). Can you edit your question to add more information about what you mean by format?

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not document how to do this, so you would need to be very careful and know how to erase a portion of the Mac. And yes, it’s technically possible to selectively erase and then reinstall macOS if you have a good second system to rescue things if you render your system drive in-bootable.

There’s no easy way to document foolproof steps, but [lots of dual](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Triple%20boot%20) and [triple boot expertise here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Dual%20boot%20). If you have a 100% surefire way to back up everything and restore it - including windows, you can proceed to experiment. You will be using commands with no undo in this step, so you might spend less time working on being able to reinstall Windows and follow Apple’s much easier erase and restore process. That is well documented and well supported.

We use WinClone at work and it is amazing. https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/

Comment: Do windows have any option like Time Machine?

Comment: I recommend https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/ and will edit my answer @Shushanto

Comment: Its a paid app, do recommend some similar free apps or crack for winclone9.

Comment: Absolutely do not pirate software. It’s ok to value your time high or low, but stealing is very poor form.

Comment: Do we have any alternative for winclone ? which is free.

Comment: There are two other apps which partially cover what WinClone can do. Neither is free. There is nothing as good as WinClone for this task.